# How to group Ruby enumerable/array by more than one field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, grouping, enumerable

I have a data structure Event:

```
Event = Struct.new(:action, :date, :id)

data= []
data << Event.new('action1', '1/8/2014', 1)
data << Event.new('action1', '1/8/2014', 2)
data << Event.new('action1', '1/8/2014', 3)
data << Event.new('action1', '8/8/2014', 4)
data << Event.new('action2', '1/8/2014', 5)
data << Event.new('action2', '2/8/2014', 6)
data << Event.new('action2', '2/8/2014', 7)
```

I want to group data based on *action* and *date*, to get final result:

```
{ 
 "action1" => {'1/8/2014' => 3, '8/8/2014' => 1 },
 "action2" => {'1/8/2014' => 1, '2/8/2014' => 2 }
}
```

The final result shows that action1 repeated 3 times at '1/8/2014' and one time at '8/8/2014'. And action2 one time at '1/8/2014' and two times at '2/8/2014'.

I tried to group results first by action using `#group_by{|x| x.action}` then tried to use inject but my solution is anything but simple.

Comment: My bad forgot one bracket. It's supposed to be a hash.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Please edit your question and make it clear. My answer will be hidden until you make your question clear.

Comment: I want to group results based on action and date. As for example, action1 repeated 3 times at '1/8/2014' and one time at '8/8/2014'. And action2 one time at '1/8/2014' and two times at '2/8/2014'.

Comment: We know that you want to group results based on action and date. What do the value numbers stand for? Explain it in words, not only by examples.

Comment: So you want the values to represent the number of times there is an `Event` object. Why couldn't you write so?

Comment: Count of each action by that date. Lets say I have action1 happened twice by 1st of august and 5 times at 6th of August, so I want to say that by 1st of August, action1 repeated twice and 5 times by 6th of August. So ("action1" => {'1/8/2014' => 3, '8/8/2014' => 1 }) means that action1 happened 3 times by 1st of August and 1 time by 8th of August.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = 0}}
.tap{|h| data.each{|e| h[e.action][e.date] += 1}}
```

result `h` is:

```
{
  "action1" => {"1/8/2014" => 3, "8/8/2014" => 1},
  "action2" => {"1/8/2014" => 1, "2/8/2014" => 2}
}
```

or,

```
data.each_with_object(Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = 0}}) do
  |e, h| h[e.action][e.date] += 1
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your willing to help @sawa. The result is not what I want tho. I want to group results based on date. As for example I'm not supposed to get "1/8/2014" => 5. Since there is only one action2 at that date 1/8/2014.

Comment: You could make it a nice one-liner by putting the second line in  `.tap { |h| ... }`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for the suggestion. I had made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

@sawa has given a lovely solution, but here are two more.  The first I rather like, the second, not so much, though I think it could be simplified some.

**#1**

This one makes use of the form of [Hash#update](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge`) that takes a block. The block only comes into play for key-values pairs for which the key is contained by both the hash being built and that  hash being merged. Recall that block variables can be replaced by an underscore (or an underscore followed by a descriptor, such as `_key`) when the block variable is not used within the block. (Use of the underscore merely draws attention to that.)

```
data.each_with_object({}) do |d,h|
  h.update({ d.action=>{ d.date=>1 } }) do |_,ohash,_|
    ohash[d.date] = (ohash[d.date] || 0) + 1
    ohash
  end
end
  #=> {"action1"=>{"1/8/2014"=>3, "8/8/2014"=>1}, 
  #    "action2"=>{"1/8/2014"=>1, "2/8/2014"=>2}}
```

**#2**

This second method uses [Enumerable#group_by](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) at each of two level, to group first by action, then for each action, by date.

```
data.map { |d| [d.action, d.date] }
    .group_by(&:first)
    .tap { |h| h.keys.each { |k|
                 h[k]=h[k].group_by { |_,d| d }
                          .tap { |g| g.keys.each {|kk| g[kk]=g[kk].size} } } }
  #=> {"action1"=>{"1/8/2014"=>3, "8/8/2014"=>1}, 
  #    "action2"=>{"1/8/2014"=>1, "2/8/2014"=>2}}
```

I will gladly provide an explanation for either method if there is interest.